# Erlang lists with single numbers over 8?

Tags: list, erlang

In some weird way all the numbers over `8`, single, in  a list becomes some kind of ASCII?

```
[8] -> ["\b"]
```

Please try to help me with this one :)

Comment: Show us code where this is happening.

Comment: just write it shell, [8]. returns ["\b"], how can I avoid this ?

Comment: i want it to return [8] to me ofcourse.

Comment: This should help explain it - http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2348087/113848).

Comment: Actually you can change this behaviour. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978873/avoid-converting-numbers-to-characters-in-erlang)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I disable printing lists of small integers as strings in Erlang shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348087/can-i-disable-printing-lists-of-small-integers-as-strings-in-erlang-shell)

Answer (score 9):

[String](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id63119) is not a data type in Erlang, it's just a list of integers. But Erlang shell try to display lists as strings if possible:

```
1> S = [65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70].
"ABCDEF"
2> S = "ABCDEF".
"ABCDEF"
3> io:write(S).
[65,66,67,68,69,70]ok
4> [65, 66].
"AB"
5> [65, 66, 1].
[65,66,1]
```

Comment: But is there any way to solve it ? So it returns the number in list instead of the "string" ??

Comment: Actually, it's not a bug, it's feature. You always can use io:write/1 to print a list as is. You can also define a shorter alias for io:write/1 with shell_default or user_default modules: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell_default.html

Answer (score 2):

Print it with `~w` instead of `~p`, and your issue should go away.

`~p` tries to interpret the elements in the list as ASCII. `~w` does not.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html

### **2.11 String**

Strings are enclosed in double quotes ("), but is not a data type in Erlang. Instead a string "hello" is shorthand for the list [$h,$e,$l,$l,$o], that is [104,101,108,108,111].

Two adjacent string literals are concatenated into one. This is done at compile-time and does not incur any runtime overhead. Example:

"string" "42"

is equivalent to

"string42"