# How to get a string from a list of numbers?

Tags: string, list, erlang

I have an Erlang list of symbols: `[104, 105, 106, 107 ...]`. How can I get a string from this list: `"hijk..."`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371955/erlang-lists-with-single-numbers-over-8 for the opposite problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Strings as a datatype do not exist in Erlang. Stings are simply lists of characters.

`[104, 105, 106, 107]` and `"hijk"` are perfectly equivalent.

In fact, if you type the original list in the shell you get back the "string":

```
1> [104, 105, 106, 107].   
"hijk"
```

Comment: If you have at least one non-printable character in the list, the list will be printed as numbers