# Erlang http client body not resolving to string

Tags: string, erlang, httprequest

```
>inets:start().
>{ok, {{NewVersion, 200, NewReasonPhrase}, NewHeaders, NewBody}} = 
httpc:request(get, {"http://msn.com/", [{"connection", "close"}]},[],[]).

> NewBody. 
[60,33,100,111,99,116,121,112,101,32,104,116,109,108,62,60,
 104,116,109,108,32,120,109,108,110,115,61,34,104|...]
```

Erlang newbie here - I expected NewBody to be readable output. It hasn't so I'm guessing some of the characters can't be represented as letters by erlang? Also what does the |... syntax at the end of the result above mean exactly - is it just a shortener?

Main Q - How can I force a string like representation of the above `NewBody` list?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10276982/113848).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
io:format("~s~n", [NewBody]).
```

for "readable" representation.