# Erlang list comprehensions strange behaviour

Tags: list, erlang, list-comprehension, beam

I learn Erlang and list comprehensions now and have discovered a weird (as for me) issue.
So I have a simple list comprehension with a simple formula and without filter:

```
gen_list(List)->
[N*N || N <- List].
```

The output is correct as I expected: `gen_list([2,3,4]). [4,9,16]` Then I do this:

```
 gen_list(List)->
[N*N*N*N || N <- List].
```

And the output is correct again: `gen_list([2,3,4]).  [16,81,256]`.
But when I define formula as:`gen_list(List)->
    [N*N*N || N <- List].` I got next output:`gen_list([2,3,4]). "\b\e@"`.

What is this:`"\b\e@"`?? Why I got it only when I have three N? I can even write the formula like this:`N*N*N*N*N*N*N*N`, and the output again will be as I expected. But with three N I always got such a weird result. Can someone explain this for me?

I use ArchLinux and GNU Emacs.

Comment: @Drew Keep calm, man:) Already fixed. I thought it can be connected with Emacs in some ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\b\e@"` is Erlang's way of representing a list of integers when those integers fall in the ASCII-displayable range.

To make sure this is a list, pattern match it like so:

```
1> [A, B, C] = "\b\e@".
"\b\e@"
2> {A, B, C}.
{8,27,64}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! So you mean instead of list I should use a `tuple` for this, am i right?

Comment: You could also look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978873/avoid-converting-numbers-to-characters-in-erlang) to change the way shell display those sudo-stings.

Comment: @HarryDeveloper1212: Don't use tuples. Just bind the result to a variable and display it like this: io:format("~w", [Result]). "~w" will display the list as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In Erlang, string is actually a list, so the "\b\e@" is the same as [8,27,64]. Is's just because these numbers are ascii-printable, the erlang shell will print it as strings.

```
1>[8,27,64].
"\b\e\@"
```

you can view the ascii code of these symbols with a $ sign before it.

```
2> $\b.
8
3> $\e.
27
4> $\@.
64
```