# Elixir Koans - Enum.take with Negative Numbers Prints Ascii

Tags: elixir

I was running through some Elixir Koans and came across the following:

```
  think "taking some items the other way" do
    numbers = 1..10
    assert Enum.take(numbers, -2) == __?
  end
```

After spending a lot of time on this I finally looked at it in iex and I get:

```
'\t\n'
```

After more experimentation:

```
Enum.take(numbers, -4) == '\a\b\t\n'
Enum.take(numbers, -5) == [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Why does this print out ascii sometimes and the list I'm expecting other times?  What happens at 7?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978873/avoid-converting-numbers-to-characters-in-erlang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Elixir FAQ](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/wiki/FAQ)

Pretty-printing of lists is done by using Erlang's native function. It is designed to print lists as strings when all elements of the list are valid ASCII codes.

At 7 you have BEL '\a' (the a is for 'alert' AFIAK)

At 6 you have ACK which apparently doesn't have a printable representation

Comment: So why does adding a zero or anything string at the end of the list make it print correctly?

Comment: Because then it isn't a list of printable ASCII codes anymore.

Comment: Ah right since the last two I would be printing are not valid.