# How does the control sequence ~s work?

Tags: erlang

The following output is as I expected:

```
125> [97, 98, 99].
"abc"

126> [97, 98, 0]. 
[97,98,0]
```

But the output using `~s` is not what I expected:

```
127> io:format("~s~n", [[97, 98, 0]]).
ab^@
ok
```

How do I interpret that output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `~s` control sequence expects to get a string, a binary or an atom, and prints it "with string syntax".  As Erlang strings are just lists of integers, it tries to print `[97, 98, 0]` in this example as a string as well.  The shell on the other hand [tries to guess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2348087/113848) whether this list of integers is meant to be a string.

`^@` represents the NUL character.  You might be familiar with the [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation), where `^A` represents byte 1, since A is the 1st letter in the alphabet - or in other words, it represents the byte whose value is 64 less than the ASCII value of the character, since A is 65 in ASCII.  Extrapolate it to the 0 byte, and you'll find `@`, which is 64 in ASCII.

Comment: *You might be familiar with the caret notation,*  Nope.  Never heard of it.  Thanks.