# How to store integers in a list

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to separate an array of integers to count how many repeated numbers are there.

For this input `[10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]` I am receiving the following output:

```
#{10=>"\n\n\n\n",20=>[20,20],30=>[30],50=>"2"}
```

## Question

I would like to know how can I generate the following output

```
#{10=>[10,10,10,10],20=>[20,20],30=>[30],50=>[50]}
```

The function I am using to generate the map output is:

```
%% Next: number
%% Acc: map
separate_socks(Next, Acc) ->
    KeyExists = maps:is_key(Next, Acc),

    case KeyExists of
        true ->
            CurrentKeyList = maps:get(Next, Acc),
            maps:update(Next, [Next | CurrentKeyList], Acc);
        false -> maps:put(Next, [Next], Acc)
    end.
```

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2348087/113848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`shell:strings/1` function](https://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html#strings-1) to deal with the problem of numbers being displayed as characters. When `shell:strings(true)` is called, numbers will be printed as characters:

```
1> shell:strings(true).
true
2> [10,10,10].
"\n\n\n"
```

Calling `shell:strings(false)` will result in the numbers being printed as numbers instead:

```
3> shell:strings(false).
true
4> [10,10,10].
[10,10,10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output is actually correct. The ascii value for `\n` is 10. There is no native `string` data type in erlang. A string is nothing by a list of values. `erlang:is_list("abc")` would return true.

Try [1010, 1020, 1020, 1010, 1010, 1030, 1050, 1010, 1020] as input. It should display all numbers.

Comment: I was with another error in my code so I thought this was the cause. Many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can also format the output with [io:format()](https://erldocs.com/21.0/stdlib/io.html?i=0&search=io:format#format/1):

```
1> M = #{10=>[10,10,10,10],20=>[20,20],30=>[30],50=>[50]}.
#{10 => "\n\n\n\n",20 => [20,20],30 => [30],50 => "2"}

2> io:format("~w~n", [M]).
#{10=>[10,10,10,10],20=>[20,20],30=>[30],50=>[50]}
ok
```

> **w**
>
> Writes data with the standard syntax. This is used to output Erlang
> terms.